# Div won't cross document's boundaries and have the screen's height

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I've tried several solutions in here, and I can't seem to find one that works for me.

I have this div in the background with a lightblue color. I've set the min-height of it to match the document's height, but the problem is, that my jQuery code doesn't work.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();

if ( windowHeight > documentHeight ) {
    $("#blueBackgroundBarVertical").height = windowHeight;
}
```

Here's the CCS code:

```
#blueBackgroundBarVertical {
min-height: 631px;
width: 150px;
background-color: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.4);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin-left: 695px;
z-index: -10; }
```

I've tried to set the 'height' to 100%, but then a problem occurs for small screens, as this is 100% of the screen, so when you scroll down on the longer pages, the rest of the bar is gone in the bottom..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.height = windowHeight` Use this

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var documentHeight = $(document).height();

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (windowHeight === documentHeight) {
        $("#blueBackgroundBarVertical").height($(window).height());
    }
});
if (windowHeight === documentHeight) {
    $("#blueBackgroundBarVertical").height(windowHeight);
}
```

Also the if statement can never be true as the window and the site have the same dimensions

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/smtWJ/2/

Also make sure you have a js file

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't seem to work. Do I have to have more references than these two? (My code is in an external script.js)

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

Comment: Your js file is not being called properly. You have: <script src='ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>.

Comment: What you need is: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Wait no sorry this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Comment: If you try to increase the height in that jsfiddle, you'll see what mine looks like - white space in the bottom. Also, I don't get what you said in your updated answer.

I've set the min-height to the documents height, and my screen is like 1280px tall, so that makes a 6xx px white space. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: For some reason if you remove don't use the var on the resize then it works. Have updated

Comment: This actually worked, though I have no idea why. How come the document's height and the window's height is the same here? The document's height is obviously 631 px, which I set the min-height to, or am I wrong on how much the document is?

Comment: It's really weird I agree

Comment: I think I figured it out now. The HTML document's size counts everything (also if the site is scrillable). The window's size only counts for what you can call "The first-eye capture size". The size of the window you can see (And doesn't count the rest that you can scroll down to see). If that makes any sense? Anyway, thank you for the help. +1 I appreciate it!